# MySQL: Force different access_type with an index for IN(...)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb, database-indexes

I'm trying to tune a very simple query:

```
select * from log where user_id in (...) order by id desc limit 25
```

I just want to show the last 25 events for a group of different users ids (around 40 IDs). This query takes around 50 seconds to run (>80 million records in the table).

By executing an `EXPLAIN format=json` I can see that the `access_type` is `range`. After some exploration, a learned that if I change the number of IDs to 9, the query planner will use another kind of access: `index`.

So I'm assuming that for a large number of IDs MySQL will do a range scan between the smaller and bigger id of the group, which could make sense if the IDs were 'close', which is not always the case. Maybe somehow, this volume of extra data, becomes a problem when doing the sorting (as shown in the explain plan bellow).

**40 IDs Explain**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "log",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "app_log_user_id"
        ],
        "key": "log_user_id",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "user_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "rows": 6150,
        "filtered": 100,
        "index_condition": "(`app`.`log`.`user_id` in (<43 different ids from 12000 to 330000>))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**9 IDs Explain**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "log",
        "access_type": "index",
        "possible_keys": [
          "app_log_user_id"
        ],
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "id"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "rows": 6901,
        "filtered": 4552.8,
        "attached_condition": "(`app`.`log`.`user_id` in (< 9 ids from 12000 to 18000))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did an experiment: I divided that query in 5 other subqueries with only 9 or less IDs and applied an `UNION` to all of them, finishing with the ORDER and LIMIT clause at the end. The query plan for this query became a little mess, even with strange values saying that the number of searched rows for one of the subqueries would be 86737713 (which I think it an very wrong estimate, all the other were around 10246). Guess what? The query took "only" 6 seconds, better than 50.

I don't know which strategies are used to optimize this kind of query, but from my humble knowledge it seemed that if I could tell the Optimizer to use an `acess_type` of `index` instead `range`, it would perform better. Is that possible?

**Extra Details**

- `user_id` have a foreign key and an index.
- We use MySQL 5.6 (InnoDB)
- Table have around 80kk rows.

**SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `app_log` (
  `id`              int(11)          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp`       datetime         NOT NULL,
  `user_id`         int(11)          NOT NULL,
  `content_type_id` int(11)          NOT NULL,
  `object_id`       int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status`          int(11)                   DEFAULT NULL,
  `type`            int(11)                   DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_log_content_type_id` (`content_type_id`),
  KEY `app_log_144dd2a9` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `app_log_user_id` (`user_id`, `id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 108628300
  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE log`; something smells fishy.  And are the ids in the list numeric or strings; that is without or with quotes?

Comment: Please include indexes along with the CREATE TABLE. Also, see if a covering index helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36705/mysql-can-not-get-rid-of-using-filesort-in-a-simple-query

Comment: @RickJames I added the table definition. The IDs are numeric, no quotes involved.

Comment: What is `kk` for a unit?

Comment: @N.B. It should mean millions (very informal I suppose, I fixed anyway).

Comment: You reduce what MySQL has to inspect by specifying different values for `user_id`. The strategy MySQL uses depends on index cardinality and this is where you get varying results, there's nothing much you can do about it. The slowness almost always comes from the fact that MySQL needs to read this data after knowing where it is - your HDD constrains you. That's why we use servers with 128GB+ RAM - to store working data-set there. After MySQL finds the data, it sorts it by id, discards everything except 25 records. What you can do is use profiling to see which part takes up time.

Comment: `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT ... (your query goes here obv.); SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`. This will show you what goes down at lower level, from opening the files, sorting, buffering, sending across the network etc. This helps determine if the constraining factor is the hardware. Your query is the type that can't be written in a smart way and yield accurate results. You could help it by doing stuff `WHERE id > 50 000 000` or something similar so it skips 50 million rows, but knowing how to "help" it requires saving some data to a sort-of materialized table and it's error prone

Comment: If this were something I had to work on, I'd opt in to use a server that can yield the data fast (a nice chunk of RAM, an SSD etc.) and I'd create statistics tables that would "help" the optimizer discard a huge chunk of rows that I know are of no use to me. Some people might suggest different technologies, Rick might have a good solution too (probably does), so I'm curious to see what happens with this question. The reason I'm not answering is because I'm also unsure how to "correctly" tackle the problem. Also, please use `m` for a million, I'm really not sure why `kk` came into play :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The likely explanation:**

What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?  I would guess you are using MySQL 5.6?  (Your use of `FORMAT=JSON` confirms "at least 5.6.5".)

- 5.6.5 Introduce `eq_range_index_dive_limit`, with a default of 10.
- 5.7.4 `eq_range_index_dive_limit` default raised to 200 - affects `IN()`

**The likely workaround:**

This note *possibly* explains your 9 vs 43 items in the `IN` list.  Suggest you play with `eq_range_index_dive_limit`.

**Trivia**

KK = thousand-thousand
M, to accountants = 'mille' = thousand
MM, to accountants = million, a la KK
Lakh, to Indians = 100K
Crore, to Indians = 10M (10 million)
Billion, to Brits *used to* mean million-million; fortunately, that confusion seems to have gone away.
The distinction between 1000 and 1024 (and KB vs KiB), etc, can, for all practical purposes, be ignored in this Forum.

Comment: MySQL version 5.6.34. And it indeed work! From 49 seconds to 748ms. I changed to 200 (which is the new default for a good reason I suppose). I'll monitor it for side effects. More one question, how did you know that? Do you remember a good amount of MySQL parameters? Or should I always check the "Server System Variables Section" when trying to tune queries? (And thanks for the Trivia info)

Comment: @IsraelFonseca I have been to nearly all the MySQL conferences.  Buried in my memory was something about an improvement to `IN(list)` relating to using index versus scanning.  I have a partial list of interesting features added in each version.  From there it was some digging.  10 does seem too low.  But a fixed 200 sounds wrong, too.  Instead, it needs some function of cardinality, row count, and dispersion of values.

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - Another note:  The Optimizer went out on a limb to use `id` to avoid the filesort.  But if the 9 items had been a long ways into the scan, it would have been slower.